# Cartesian product of 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays that I want a Cartesian product of. As an example:

Customer Array:

```
[10,A]
[11,B]
```

Debtor Array:

```
[88,W]
[99,X]
```

I want to produce a new `customerDebtor` array with:

```
[10,A,88,W]
[10,A,99,X]
[11,B,88,W]
[11,B,99,X]
```

I am attempting it with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < customerArray.length; i++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < debtorArray.length; l++) {
        $.each(customerArray[i], function (ndx, val) {
            //???? push values into customerDebtorMatrix array
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jquery for this:

```
var customerArray = [[10,'A'],[11,'B']];
var debtorArray = [[88,'W'],[99,'X']];

var customerDebtorMatrix = [];
for (var i = 0; i < customerArray.length; i++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < debtorArray.length; l++) {
        customerDebtorMatrix.push(customerArray[i].concat(debtorArray[l]));
    }
}
```

`customerDebtorMatrix` will be

```
[ [ 10, 'A', 88, 'W' ],
  [ 10, 'A', 99, 'X' ],
  [ 11, 'B', 88, 'W' ],
  [ 11, 'B', 99, 'X' ] ]
```

Comment: OK - I hear you. But, if I wanted to do it with jquery, what would that look like?

Comment: @Greg: Why would you want to do it with jQuery? You could use `$.each` instead of `for` loops. But there’s also `Array.prototype.forEach` for any reasonably modern browser in the first place…

Comment: @Greg you'd need to have a nested `$.each`. It would look like `$.each(customerArray, function(k1,v1) { $.each(debtorArray, function(k2,v2) { customerDebtorMatrix.push(v1.concat(v2)); }); });`

Comment: Thanks Nirk - looks like the javascript syntax is much nicer (for a c# user).Thanks

Answer (score 3):

concatMap works well here:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // cartProd :: [a] -> [b] -> [[a, b]]
    function cartProd(xs, ys) {
        return [].concat.apply([], xs.map(function (x) {
            return [].concat.apply([], ys.map(function (y) {
                return [[x, y]];
            }));
        }));
    }

    return cartProd(["alpha", "beta", "gamma"], [1, 2, 3]);

})();
```

Returning:

```
[["alpha", 1], ["alpha", 2], ["alpha", 3], ["beta", 1], ["beta", 2], ["beta", 3], ["gamma", 1], ["gamma", 2], ["gamma", 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

### 2017 version

Using you data:

```
// Customer Array:
let c = [[10, 'A'], [11, 'B']];
// Debtor Array:
let d = [[88, 'W'], [99, 'X']];
```

### all you need is one line:

```
let r = [].concat(...c.map(c => (d.map(d => c.concat(d)))));
```

or this for compatibility with older browsers that don't support the spread syntax:

```
let r = [].concat.apply([], c.map(c => (d.map(d => c.concat(d)))));
```

You can see that `console.log(r);` prints:

```
[ [ 10, 'A', 88, 'W' ],
  [ 10, 'A', 99, 'X' ],
  [ 11, 'B', 88, 'W' ],
  [ 11, 'B', 99, 'X' ] ]
```

which is exactly what you wanted.

No loops, no pushes to arrays, no jQuery, just a few simple function calls.

For more than two arrays, see this answer:

- **[Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript/43053803#43053803)**

Answer (score 0):

Actually this would be the [Kronecker (or Tensor) Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

**Javascript code for the kronecker product of 2 arrays**

```
function kronecker_product(a, b) 
{
    var i, j, k, al = a.length, bl = b.length, abl = al*bl, ab = new Array(abl);
    i = 0; j = 0;
    for (k=0; k<abl; k++)
    {
        if ( j>=bl) {j=0; i++;}
        ab[k] = [].concat(a[i],b[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return ab;
}
```

For disambiguation let me give the code for the cartesian product as well:

```
function cartesian_product(a, b) 
{
    var al = a.length, bl = b.length;
    return [a.concat(bl>al ? new Array(bl-al) : []), b.concat(al>bl ? new Array(al-bl) : [])];
}
```

The main difference is the number of components (length) of the final result, in kronecker the length should be the product of the lengths while in cartesian it should be the sum.

**Example Kronecker**

```
var a = ["a","b"], b = ["c","d"];
console.log(kronecker_product(a,b));
```

**Output**

```
[["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "d"]]
```

**Example Cartesian**

```
var a = ["a","b"], b = ["c","d"];
console.log(cartesian_product(a,b));
```

**Output**

```
 [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
```